# How to unstack dataframe with 2 column index?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert my input dataframe to output, i tried with stacking/unstacking. The index is 2 different columns

INPUT DATAFRAME :

```
id   peid  attr_name  attr_val
1     X      Type       Box
1     X      Color      Black
2     Y      Type       Square
2     Y      Color      Red
```

EDIT: I used 
df.set_index(['id','peid','attr_name'], append=True).unstack()

The DataFrame currently :

```
id   peid    Type       Color
1     X      None       Black
1     X      Box        None
2     Y      None       Red
2     Y      Square     None
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT DATAFRAME :

```
id   peid  Type  Color
1     X    Box    Black
2     Y    Square Red
```

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['id','peid'], columns='attr_name', values='attr_val', aggfunc='first')`

Comment: Oh Yes! I thought pivot table was only for number values !